# web.config transformer does nothing

Tags: asp.net, web-config, transformer-model

I'm trying to use the web.config transformer, but it does nothing.
Here is my last part of web.config:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IUserInterfaceService" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />

      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>

</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://[WhiteOPS User Interface]:[Port]/UIService/UserInterfaceService/"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IUserInterfaceService"
    contract="UserInterface.IUserInterfaceService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IUserInterfaceService" />
</client>
```

and here is my web.debug.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <endpoint name="BasicHttpBinding_IUserInterfaceService" address="http://localhost:80/UIService/UserInterfaceService/"
   xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
```

when i run (with or without debuging mode) in the debug configuration, i'm getting an error that this line cannot compiled:

```
<endpoint address="http://[WhiteOPS User Interface]:[Port]/UIService/UserInterfaceService/"
binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IUserInterfaceService"
contract="UserInterface.IUserInterfaceService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IUserInterfaceService" />
```

so why the transformation not happening?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You need to build it up in the same structure as your other web.config.

So you need to wrap it with the same `<client>` tag, so that the transformer can find it in the same location.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <client>
      <endpoint name="BasicHttpBinding_IUserInterfaceService" address="http://localhost:80/UIService/UserInterfaceService/" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
  </client>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I did that already (in fact i build the whole tree from the system model node), I also tried to use the "Replace" instead of the "setAttributes", it still not working......